# Coalesce issue when trying to return number of dups

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I have a @NumberOfDups variable that I'm trying to populate with a number of dups and if no records are returned then assign a 0 to the variable. I get the error Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @NumberOfDups int; 
SET @NumberofDups = (
    SELECT COALESCE(
    (SELECT APPID, SiteID, CustomerID, Status, Effective_Date, End_Date, AppType, EDCode, Count(APPID)
    FROM Mcsfwisdtest.FRA.dbo.vw_HHSurvey
    WHERE CustomerID NOT LIKE ('%~%')
    GROUP BY APPID, SiteID, CustomerID, Status, Effective_Date, End_Date, AppType, EDCode
    HAVING COUNT(APPID) > 1),0)
)
```

Comment: The query `SELECT APPID,...` return a table, and then you put it in the COALESCE. It is like COALESCE(a table, 0). That's why you got the error.

Answer (score 1):

This counts duplicates as the sum of `count(appid)-1`:

```
declare @NumberOfDups int;

set @NumberofDups = coalesce(
  (select sum(Duplicates)
    from (
     select 
      Duplicates=Count(APPID)-1
     from Mcsfwisdtest.FRA.dbo.vw_HHSurvey
     where CustomerID not like ('%~%')
     group by APPID
      , SiteID
      , CustomerID
      , status
      , Effective_Date
      , End_Date
      , AppType
      , EDCode
     having COUNT(APPID) > 1
     ) as d
     ), 0)
```

Comment: That got it.  Thank for your help!  That makes sense now.  Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if I understand your question correctly.

```
DECLARE @NumberOfDups int; 


SELECT @NumberofDups = COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT APPID, SiteID, CustomerID, Status, Effective_Date, End_Date, AppType, EDCode, Count(APPID)
FROM Mcsfwisdtest.FRA.dbo.vw_HHSurvey
WHERE CustomerID NOT LIKE ('%~%')
GROUP BY APPID, SiteID, CustomerID, Status, Effective_Date, End_Date, AppType, EDCode
HAVING COUNT(APPID) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.